# matplotlib LaTeX table width

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, tex

I'm creating a report in matplotlib and saving it to an A4 page file. This report requires a table which I am creating using the LaTeX functionality, however I'm having some issue with table sizing.

I have tried multiple ways of sizing the table, including `\resizebox` and using tabular with `{m{1in} | ...}` in the spec section, but none of them size the table properly, am I missing something here? Below is a snippit of the code I've got:

```
TeX = '''\begin{tabular}{| c{1in} | c{1in} |}
         data1 & data2 \\
         data3 & data4 \\ hline \end{tabular}'''
```

or

```
TeX = '''\resizebox{5in}{5in}{\begin{tabular}{| c{1in} | c{1in} |}
         data1 & data2 \\
         data3 & data4 \\ hline \end{tabular}}'''
```

followed by:

```
page = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27,11.69))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(5,6)
ax_table = plt.subplot(gs[3:,:])
ax_table.axis('off')
ax_table.text(0,0,TeX,size=6,va='center')
plt.show()
```

Thanks

AW

Comment: Do you have `rcParams['text.usetex'] = True`?

Comment: Yep, the table prints fine, I just can't change the width of it, or it's columns.